# -ms- transform not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transform

i am having some issue with -ms-transform working in IE.

Everything is fine in chrome and ff, but i simply can not get it to work in internet explorer.

I am using dabblets's [prefixfree](http://dabblet.com/code/prefixfree.min.js) js file.

Here is the html file:

http://ikw.inf.elte.hu/wp-content/themes/eit/social/index.html

Could you please help me out to get it work as it work in chrome?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about normal `transform`? What IE version?

Comment: [questions should include all relevant code and not simply links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code) please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: btw, normal transform is included in the css: 

`transform: rotateY(100deg);`

Answer (score 0):

IE sadly does not support `preserve-3d` in transformations. You will have to manually calculate the individual transformations of the child elements instead.

Comment: Or, can i disable the CSS for IE? It would be better with no transations than this dysfunctional...